# 3 Variables, One Equation

Tags: diophantine-equations

What triples (x, y, z) will satisfy the following equation?:

$x^2$ + $y^2$ + $z^2$ = $7(x+y+z)$

I tried factoring the left side as $(x+y+z)^2 - 2xyz$, and I wasn't sure how to continue from there.

EDIT: x, y, and z are positive integers.

Comment: What are $x,y,z$? Integers?

Comment: Try this idea: $x(x-7) + y(y-7) + z(z-7) = 0$. This has 56 integer solutions. Its a sphere.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the factoring you do, it might help instead to group terms and rewrite to be in the form $(x-7/2)^2 + (y-7/2)^2 + (z-7/2)^2 = c$, which is now asking for integer points on some sphere.

Comment: How would I go about finding positive integer points on a sphere?

Comment: I'll confess that I used brute force more or less, although some effort was saved by my knowledge of the integers that are the sum of two squares.